# Failing claim gives 500 instead of 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, wif, claims-based-identity

We use the Claims principal attribute from our MVC controllers. Problem is if a unauthorized user access the site he gets a 500 instead of a 403 which is not very user friendly (If he gets a 403 he knows he needs to call help desk to order correct user privilege).

What is the correct way of making sure the Security exception results in a 403? I've seen alot of creative ways when googling, but not a solid solution.

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "Foo", Operation = "Post")]
```

Comment: 500 usually means there is an error on the server. What is that error? and show us some code please. I suspect you use `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` - that is not the best way in MVC app, as this value not always what you want it to be, especially for unauthenticated users.

Comment: We use the ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute on our MVCcontroller methods, if the user is not Authorized it throws a SecurityException which will end up as a 500 instead of a 403 which is not very user friendly. The user does not understand that he needs to get additional privileges to access said function of the system

Comment: Updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own Claims attribute like trailmax suggested works, but only for code in the Web layer, but business logic below can still use the claims attribute. A better solution to my problem is to use a custom `HandleErrorAttribute`

```
public class HandleClaimsErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Exception is SecurityException)            
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;            

    }
}
```

http://andersmalmgren.com/2015/01/23/mvc-custom-errors-http-status-codes-and-securityexception/

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are trying to do. `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` is not  intended for use in MVC app. However, MVC does not have a similar attribute that works in similar manner, so you'll need to implement one yourself.

You can take my naive implementation as a basis for your code:

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string ClaimType { get; private set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; private set; }

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue)
    {
        ClaimType = claimType;
        ClaimValue = claimValue;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (user.HasClaim(ClaimType, ClaimValue))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                // need to have controller Errors with action Unauthorised
                {"controller", "Errors"},
                {"action", "Unauthorised"}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have been playing with claims authentication for a while now and loaded it on [GitHub](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation) (there are 2 branches, main one is more advanced). You are welcome to poke about and see how it works. I've used this approach in 2 high-scale production projects with success, so must be doing it right -)

Comment: Stupid me, did the same thing in another project for Enterprise library Rule    authorization. Any reason you use OnAuthorization and handle the error redirect in the Attribute? If you instead override AutorizeCore and return true/false MVC will use the built in custom errors pipline

Comment: Can't remember just now, but there was a reason for that. Possibly because I could control where I redirect users - and it is nice to tell them that they don't have permissions, rather than redirecting them to a login page without a message why.

Comment: This is something we are actively iterating on currently for Asp.Net 5/MVC, feel free to take a look/comment if you have any opinions... https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/141 (We are going in a policy driven direction, where policies can support claim requirements)